# Ignorar paréntesis en html pero si mostrarlos

Tags: javascript

Estoy queriendo ingresar en un html un array de "funciones" por así decirlo en los cuales pueda dar click en uno de ellos, y que en la web se pueda ver el resultado de sus links () pero por los parentesis el html hace que no lo tomen en cuenta. De esta manera:

```js
const funcNames = ['paciente.obtener', 'paciente.buscar', 'paciente.contiene']
    var tmp = "";
    for (var i = funcNames.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     tmp = `<a>${funcNames[i]}(${tmp})</a>`;
    }
    //Resultado en consola
    console.log(tmp);
```

Esto funciona correctamente pero al pasar html este lo mal interpreta por los paréntesis al parecer ya que lo que deseo es que dentro de un link haya otro link. hay otra forma de hacer esto? no se si pueda ignorar los paréntesis.

De tal manera que quede:

```
<a>funcionpadre(<a>funcionhijo()</a>)</a>
```

Comment: un vinculo de tipo a es una redireccion.. vos queres hacer un onclick?

Comment: Buena pregunta. si solo un onclick para abrir un modal

Comment: No entiendo  la diferencia entre lo que esperas y lo que hace.

Comment: Entonces, habria que reformular la pregunta no?